# Bug in ToolTip behaviour for disabled controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I noticed a very strange behaviour with tooltips in Windowsforms and I am not sure if this is a (known) bug of the framework (.NET 4):
I have two buttons sitting right next to each other. Both have a tooltip assigned. Now I disable one of the controls. Naturally the tooltip will not show for disabled controls. Here's when it gets strange: When I move the cursor over the enabled button to the inactive without waiting for the tooltip to appear on the enabled control, it opens up on the disabled control - and disappears again instantly.

The only way to prevent this is a rather nasty workaround in the popup event handler of the tooltip. I check if the associated control is disabled and if so, cancel the action.
Is there any other way to prevent this in the first place?

//edit: Just confirmed that the bug still exists in .NET 4.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it seems to be a bug in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below method

```
ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
button2.Enabled = false;

if (!button2.Enabled)
{
    tt.SetToolTip(this.button2, "");
}
else
{
    tt.SetToolTip(this.button2, "Button2");
}
tt.SetToolTip(this.button1, "Button1");
```

### Updated:

```
ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
tt.ShowAlways = false;
button2.Enabled = false;

if (button2.Enabled)
{
    tt.SetToolTip(this.button2, "Button2");
}
else
{
    tt.ShowAlways = false; 
}

tt.SetToolTip(this.button1, "Button1");
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but won't `tt.SetToolTip(this.button2, "");` show a blank tooltip (not remove it)?

Comment: Please see my updated answer if you dont want to set tool tip for disabled controls.

Comment: Also By not setting in tool tip, you can overcome this situation. Finally, this seems to be a Bug.

Comment: I know that there are workarounds, my question was more in the direction if this is actually intended behaviour or a bug in the framework? I mean it does not show tooltips for disabled controls, so why does it flicker?

Comment: As i told in my previous comment, this seems to be bug. This is not expected behaviour of tool tip.